# AS3 - image quality to load in MovieClips while preserving Quality/Performance

Tags: android, ios, actionscript-3, flash, air

I have created an AS3 - Adobe air game, targeting both android and ios platforms. 
Currently, i create a movie clip inside the library, and put a PNG image inside of the freshly created movie clip. So my architecture would be a PNG image inside a movie clip.
Inside my classes, i keep creating instances of the MovieClip and load it randomly to the Stage, and everything is working fine. The only problem i think about is i can see small glitching while the movie clip is changing it's Y Position ( Movie clips keeps moving from top to bottom, disappear when they reach bottom, and i re-create them from the start, Falling objects from the Sky concept). 
That's why i can see them moving with a glitch. I recently read that there is something in flash that uses BitmapData and that process, but i don't think i can apply it to my code, or at least yet i dunno how, since all the tutorials i found would cost me to litterally re-code everything
That's why i need to know, if i load a different image type in the movie clip, would it get better or it won't do anything? 
If so, what type would it be the best to use, while preserving good quality and great performance? I tried to mess around with Flash's Renderer, between CPU and GPU, i found that GPU is faster in a way, since i really need optimal performance, am i missing something?

Comment: First, it is not that simple to use GPU to render content, you need a framework like Gamua Starling in order to do so. Second, you could start with setting **smoothing** to **true** for your raster images, it really helps to smooth things on subpixel scale.

Comment: Try importing the image at double the dimensions, then scale it to 50% within your movie clip. Try using a .jpg format with a mask if you need transparency. And as Organis mentions, set smoothing to true for the bitmap.